# Is it possible to embed a local webpage into a pyforms webpage?

Tags: python, pyforms

I would like to create a simple in-browser GUI for a Python app. One reason I would like to use [Pyforms Web](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/projects/Pyforms-WEB/en/v4/) for this is that it seems to require little to no HTML/CSS/JS experience.

I would like it to be able to include an embedded local webpage, namely an interactive Plotly dash app, in the local Pyforms webpage. Is this possible using Pyforms?

There is [no mention](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/projects/Pyforms-WEB/en/v4/search.html?q=embed&check_keywords=yes&area=default) of embedding in the Pyforms documentation, and I have tried searching for the same thing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
**1. create a Plotly Dash app**

    import dash
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    import plotly.express as px
    import pandas as pd

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# -make a dataframe
# -make a bar chart with plotly express
--------------------------------------------

**2. create a main Pyforms web app**

    from pyforms_web.web import WebApplication
from pyforms_web.web.middleware import WebMiddleware
import web

    render = web.template.render('templates/')

    #-class app(webapp)
# -def init()
# -def home()
# -def routes()

    if whatever == '__main__':
from Pyforms_web.web import run_app
run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

------------------------------------------
**3. make some HTML**



    #<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8050" width="100%" height="500px"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>




--------------------
**4. run 1 and 2 at the same time --> 2 terminals or import multiprocessing**
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).